# I wrote file in python 2.7 but cannot find the output in the working directory

Tags: python, csv

I wrote a large dictionary to csv, the code ran without errors but I can't find the file in the working directory.

Before running the code I set up the working directory but now I can't seem to find the output anywhere in the hard drive.

I used `csv.Dictwriter` and also added `f.close()` in the end of the code.

What could be possible problem?
I'm using a public computer, could this have any thing to do with this issue?

The code:

```
os.chdir("/afs/ir.xxxx.edu/users/e/h/nogbob/Documents/")
keys = emails[0].keys()

import csv
with open('Emails2.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(emails)

output_file.close()
```

Comment: We really have to see the code for that..

Comment: @OferArial I just did, could you take a look?

Comment: Using `with open` already closes the file for you, delete the last line..

Comment: @OferArial That's what I original ran, but still did not produce an output file...

Comment: You get no errors? Try creating a file in that directory using another script, without even writing anything to it.

Comment: @OferArial Oh I found it!! strangely it was not in the working directory as I wrote above, it was in the directory right above python.

Comment: Add `print(os.path.exists("/afs/ir.xxxx.edu/users/e/h/nogbob/Documents/Emails2.csv"))` at the end of the script to check if the file actually exists. You could be looking in the wrong directory.

Comment: good :) good luck!